# C++ Receiving error with pure virtual function, "variable or field 'x' declared as void"

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm new to inheritance/abstract classes/polymorphism. For the record, I've been able to compile and run programs using derived objects from abstract classes before, but for some reason, I'm unable to do so now.

Here is the pure virtual function, within the abstract base class
declaration 'AerialVehicle.h':

```
virtual void fly = 0; //error: variable or field 'fly' declared void
```

Now here is the derived class "TF18.h"

```
void TF18::fly()
{
cout << "\n\t--Flying--\n"
     << getName() << " is flying...\n"
     << "Wingspan: " << getWingspan() << "\n"
     << "Max Altitude: " << getMaxAlt() << "\n"
     << "Seats: " << getSeats() << "\n"
     << "Engines: " << getEngines() << "\n";
}
```

This program is only a means to understand the concepts more clearly. I've not added any other member functions to TF18. This is puzzling me, as I've been able to create programs in this style up until now. Does the pure virtual function absolutely require a return value?

I'm using CodeBlocks w/ GNU GCC Compiler. I've tried other compilers as well, and even copy/pasted the code to Orwell DevC++ using various compilers, but to no avail :(

Lastly, I am using ifndef/define/endif in my headers.

Comment: If `fly` should be a function, it must be `fly()`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the parentheses in the function declaration

```
virtual void fly() = 0;
                ^^
```